# ImportError: No module named management.commands.check

Tags: python, django, importerror

I want to check my app, but i have an error(

```
   $ python manage.py check
     Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/alexey/.local/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alexey/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alexey/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/alexey/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in   import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named management.commands.check
```

Command "dbshell" give out similar result.
What is wrong?

Comment: Which version of Django do you have, and how did you install it?

Comment: >>> django.VERSION
(1, 9, 5, 'final', 0)

I installed django via pip